# Multi Project Build Definition From Collection Level

Tags: tfs-2015, build-definition

We have a TFS C# Collection with projects like this:

OurCollection
   OurControls
   OurDBFuntions
   OurCommonCode
   Project1
   Project2

Building Project1 or Project2 requires builds of all the "Our" projects.  TFS will not let me create a build definition in the OurCollection space - it requires me to be in one of the Project spaces.  But I can't load from the repository to get all the "Our" stuff so that Project1 or Project2 can compile, link, and complete.
 The Configuration has links to all the "Our" projects and requires them to build before building the Project1 or Project2, but the sln and all other source files are not downloaded from the repository and the pathing is limited to subfolders of $/Project1.

Can I accomplish what I need to do?

Thanks,
Tony

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

We have several projects - the "Our. . ." projects, which build as DLLs, linked as references.  Each "Our. . ." project has its own solution and needs to be built before our Project1 is built.  The Configuration Manager has them marked to build and we have a build order.  When I create a build definition, it lets me point to a solution in the Project1 folder - which works so far.  But it doesn't download from source control for the other projects.  So the specified configuration can't find the "Our. . ." solutions and then the Project1 build can't find the references and everything fails.

I basically need to have the folder set to the collection level so I can get all the projects from source control rather than just Project1.

I'm not sure what the "Shared Projects" feature is and don't find a reference in any of the documentation on how to set up a build definition.

Thanks,
Tony

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

I'm trying to create a new TFS 2015 build definition . . . and to make it clear, here's my hierarchy

OurCollection

1. Team Project OurControls
2. Team Project OurDBFunctions
3. Team Project OurCommonCode
4. Team Project Project1

   1. ProjectGUI
   2. ProjectRules
   3. ProjectDBAccess
5. Team Project Project2

One of my problems is that, in the build definition, when I go to Source Settings and try and add a referenced solution path, it will only add a path that is below the TEAM Project1 level.  I can't go back and add a path to a different Team Project in the OurCollection.  It will only allow me to add a referenced solution path that is below the Team Project Project1 path in the hierarchy.

So if I move the Team Project OurControls solution under TEAM Project Project1, now I can add it.  But TEAM Project Project2 can't.

Several other post seem to indicate getting build definitions set at the collection level.  When I try that, it won't let me - I have to pick a TEAM project.  Once I pick a TEAM project, I'm stuck in that tree.

So maybe the question is - how do I create build definitions at the collection level?  When I go to server:8080/TFS/OurCollection, I do not get a Build Tab.  I have to go to server:8080/TFS/OurCollection/Project1 to get a Build tab.

Thanks for any help,
Tony

Comment: Which kind of build are you using? The new vnext build or the old xaml build?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the following folder structure

```
 C#Collection
   OurCollection (project)
   OurControls   (project)
   OurDBFuntions (project)
   OurCommonCode (project)
   Solution1  (sln including project1)
   Solution2  (sln including project1)
```

The 'our projects' can shared across multiple Visual Studio solutions. They don't need to added to the solutions, you can using the 'Shared Projects' feature, just adding them by doing 'Add existing project'. Then you can create one definition for solution1 and build the project1 sucessful by selecting the soulution1.

```
 Soulution1
    OurCollection (project)
    OurControls   (project)
    OurDBFuntions (project)
    OurCommonCode (project)
    project1
```